# Maximum recursion depth exceeded: how can i work around this

Tags: python, recursion, sudoku

So i'm making a sudoku solver. Code for the recursive solver function is pasted below. Let me know if you want me to explain any part of my code, i JUST got it to work so its not the most robust.

The attempts variable basically keeps track of how many attempts have been made on each square, and essentially helps to define which subtrees and leaf nodes to use on each iteration.

To my question: I keep getting the **RecursionError: max recursion depth exceeded**, and was looking for some advice on how to work around this? Should i restructure my code around a *while loop*, is there a way I can *simplify my code*, is there a way i can *safely* override this error, let me know.

```
def solve(board, count=0, tree=0):
    global attempts
    global originalBoard

    # breaks recursive loop when reached the end of the board
    if count >= 80:
        print(board)
        return board

    # sets up global variables for beginning of solution
    elif count == 0:
        attempts = np.zeros((9, 9), int)
        originalBoard = board.copy()

    # converts count into x and y, allows iteration from left to right (rows)
    x = count % 9
    y = count // 9

    # skips iteration if theres already an original value there
    if board[x, y] != 0 and board[x, y] == originalBoard[x, y]:
        return solve(board, count + 1)

    # collects all possible solutions
    solutions = possibleSolutions(board, count)
    numOfSolutions = len(solutions)
    validSolutions = solutions[tree:]
    numOfValidSolutions = len(validSolutions)

    # if we've reached the end of a specific subtree, we reset, go back one, and reset the tree
    if tree > numOfSolutions:
        board[count % 9, count // 9] = originalBoard[count % 9, count // 9]     # reset value
        count -= 1                                                              # go back one
        tree = attempts[count % 9, count // 9]                                  # picks up where left off
        return solve(board, count, tree)


    attempts[count % 9, count // 9] = tree

    if numOfValidSolutions >= 1:
        board[x, y] = validSolutions[0]
        return solve(board, count + 1)
    
    elif numOfValidSolutions == 0:
        count -= 1                                                              # go back
        attempts[count % 9, count // 9] += 1
        tree = attempts[count % 9, count // 9]                                  # move on to next leaf node
        board[count % 9, count // 9] = originalBoard[count % 9, count // 9]     # reset failed value
        return solve(board, count, tree)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is using tail recursion - each branch will call `solve` method just once. That means that it shouldn't be that hard to rewrite that into a loop without recursion.

But if you just want to rise the limit of recursion depth you can do it with code:

```
import sys 

sys.setrecursionlimit(10**6)
```

Default limit is `10**4`.